# Reproduce simple pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a situation with my data. I like the behaviour of .plot() over a data frame. But sometimes it doesn't work, because the frequency of the time index is not an integer.

But reproducing the plot in matplotlib is OK. Just ugly.

The part that bother me the most is the settings of the x axis. The tick frequency and the limits. Is there any easy way that I can reproduce this behaviour in matplotlib?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create Data
f = lambda x: np.sin(0.1*x) + 0.1*np.random.randn(1,x.shape[0])
x = np.arange(0,217,0.001)
y = f(x)

# Create DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame(y.transpose(), columns=['dp'], index=None)
data['t'] = pd.date_range('2021-01-01 14:32:09', periods=len(data['dp']),freq='ms')
data.set_index('t', inplace=True)

# Pandas plot()
data.plot()

# Matplotlib plot (ugly x-axis)
plt.plot(data.index,data['dp'])
```

EDIT: Basically, what I want to achieve is a similar spacing in the xtics labels, and the tight margin adjust of the values. Legends and axis title, I can do them

**Pandas output**

[image: Pandas output]

**Matplotlib output**

[image: matplotlib output]

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `ewww`? What *exactly* do you *want* to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post to provide more detaills. I was on my morning commute and arrived at my destination and couldn't add further details

Comment: In case you are wondering why I need to reproduce the .plot() behaviour. Change the `freq='ms'`to for example `'2.5ms'`. The data.plot() will crash the python kernel. But in matplotlib it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some matplotlib date utilities:

- [**`Figure.autofmt_xdate()`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.FigureBase.autofmt_xdate) to unrotate and center the date labels
- [**`Axis.set_major_locator()`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_locator.html) to change the interval to 1 min
- [**`Axis.set_major_formatter()`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_formatter.html) to reformat as `%H:%M`

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data.index, data['dp'])

import matplotlib.dates as mdates
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=0, ha='center')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

# uncomment to remove the first `xtick`
# ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[1:])
```

[image: with mdates formatting]

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for your input.

Comment: This really helped. I just need to add some stuff for the range. basically ax.margins(0)